# Is "git checkout --patch" incompatible with autocrlf=true?

Tags: windows, git

On my windows machine I'm considering setting `autocrlf = true` in my .gitconfig. Others on my team have it set this way and we've ended up with a mix of `lf` & `crlf` in the repo. I've considered a few options and this seems like the path of least resistance...

One thing I've noticed is that `git checkout -p` fails with the error `patch does not apply` when `autocrlf = true`. If I change it back to `false` it works as expected.

Is `autcrlf = true` incompatible with `checkout --patch` or is do I need to set some other option to get it to work?

Interestingly `git add --patch` works as expected with `autocrlf = true`.

Comment: For posterity.. This helped me understand the various git eol fix options https://adaptivepatchwork.com/2012/03/01/mind-the-end-of-your-line/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes**, `git checkout --patch` works properly with line ending translation.  The patch almost certainly isn't applying because you have mismatched configuration.

Everybody on your team needs to use the *same* line ending configuration.  `core.autocrlf=true` isn't an option that one person on a team can enable; everybody needs the *same* settings.  That's because if you have `core.autocrlf=false`, then you're telling Git that the contents on disk are identical to the contents in the repository.  If you're on Windows, that means that you're checking in files with Windows-style line endings (`\r\n`).  If you have a colleague who enables `core.autocrlf=true`, then you're telling Git that the contents on disk have Windows-style line endings while the contents in the repository have Unix style line endings (`\n`).

But your colleague has told git a lie, since the repository contents actually have `\r\n` in them.

A variety of strange things can occur when these settings are mismatched, including things like patches failing to apply.

You should instead:

1. Set `* text=auto` in your `.gitattributes` file.  This ensures that everybody working in the repository has the same settings, since the configuration is actually *checked in* and not something that everybody has to remember to configure properly.
2. Renormalize the repository, so that the repository contents actually match what you've claimed.  You can do this by `git add --renormalize .` and checking the contents in.

Once you've done this (and everybody has updated your local working folders), your `git apply --patch` should behave correctly.

Comment: This did the trick. Thanks! I did opt to specify `text` or `binary` explicitly in .gitattributes. `* text=auto` gives me flashbacks of vss corrupting binary files.

Comment: lol that's fair.  git is pretty good about detecting binaries, but I agree that being explicit is always better.

Comment: Turns out git is better than I am at detecting binaries.. We had a few utf16 xml files for regression tests that got mangled with `*.xml text`. I tried out `* text=auto` and it got everything right.